# can't retrieve the wanted data out from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, data-binding, ado.net

I have created an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2010. I am having trouble in retrieving the data i wanted from the two dates i selected from the date picker. once i select the 2 dates, it just keep displaying all the data out and not the dates that i have selected.

This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string startdate = (string)Session["startdate"];
    string enddate = (string)Session["enddate"];
    DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
    DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);

    if (DateTime.Compare(two, one)>=0)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ncpsdbb;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "')", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
       GridView1.Visible = false;
       string strMsg = " Data not found for the choosen dates.";
       Response.Write("<script>alert('" + strMsg + "')</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/). You should ***never*** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial observation is that there is a `)` in your SQL with *no matching `(`* - I wonder if your command is simply throwing an exception...?

The first thing I would try is parameterizing it; in addition to being a *really really good idea anyway*, it could avoid formatting (dd/MM vs MM/dd) issues in the dates:

```
if(two >= one)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ncpsdbb;Integrated Security=True"))
    using(var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN @start AND @end", conn))
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
    {
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", one);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", two);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: once it reaches da.Fill(ds); i got this error : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: @PorWeiting what is the column type of `TimeDate` ? i.e. how is that defined in the database?

Comment: my column type for TimeDate is : nvarchar(50)

Comment: @PorWeiting yeah, that's a problem; that column should be `date` or `datetime` - otherwise you are comparing *at best* alphabetically. Dates in databases should be stored *as typed values*

Comment: the database type date/datetime can store dd/mm/yyyy formatted data?

Comment: @PorWeiting dates/times ***do not have a format***. A date is a date is a date. In the same way that integers do not have a notion of bold and italics. Your UI should deal with formatting; the database should deal with storing the actual values. Anywhere that your database tools are displaying the date *in a particular format*, that is a feature of the tool you are using - it is not part of the data itself.

Comment: i have tried running it. but i still gotten this error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. please help. thanks you =)

Answer (score 1):

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ncpsdbb;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate", conn);

    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("startDate" <Your start date>);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("endDate" <Your end date>);

    ...
```

Also notice the error with parantheses in your command string.